# testrpc's addresses and checksum

Tags: addresses, testrpc, eip

When testrpc starts, it outputs the generated addresses, but all in lower case.
What's a lightweight way to get their [EIP55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55) checksummed format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure testrpc is running. From a second terminal (opened by running `node`), run:

```
> Web3 = require('web3')
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

This should shoot out a list of all available commands, and leave you with a command prompt. From the prompt you can then run the appropriate command:

```
> web3.toChecksumAddress('0x65601db7431427e32ce2d60e6a373bc7a7f68eb4')
'0x65601DB7431427E32Ce2d60e6a373bc7A7F68EB4'
```

Comment: That's a better answer than mine. Particularly as "lightweight" is a criteria.

Comment: web3 no longer has tochecksum address?

Answer (score 1):

In that link you supplied there is code that gives your answer:

```
// Make a checksum address
var toChecksumAddress = function (address) {    
    address = address.toLowerCase().replace('0x','');
    var addressHash = web3.sha3(address);
    var checksumAddress = '0x';

    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++ ) { 
        // If ith character is 9 to f then make it uppercase 
        if (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7) {
          checksumAddress += address[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
            checksumAddress += address[i];
        }
    }
    return checksumAddress;
};
```

When you say

> What's a lightweight way to get their EIP55 checksummed format?

Are you looking for lighterweight code than that?

Comment: That code has an error in it :-) It should be `if (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7)` not `> 8`. It might be worth grabbing the code that was committed, rather than code talked about in the thread, just to be safe.